# for loop ends prematurely when objects are removed

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

Hi I have a problem with a `for` loop.

It looks like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < ObjectManager.Instance.Objects.Count; i++)
{
   if (ObjectManager.Instance.Objects[i] is Asteroid)
   {
      ObjectManager.Instance.Objects.Remove(ObjectManager.Instance.Objects[i]);
   }
}
```

But the count gets shorter while I remove objects, which causes the loop to end prematurely. Is there a way to do this without a bunch of extra loops.

Comment: What about counting in reverse order.

Comment: What is the type of `ObjectManager.Instance.Objects`?

Comment: You can loop backwards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you loop *backward*?

```
// Just change the order from Count - 1 down to 0 
for (int i = ObjectManager.Instance.Objects.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
   if (ObjectManager.Instance.Objects[i] is Asteroid)
   {
      ObjectManager.Instance.Objects.Remove(ObjectManager.Instance.Objects[i]);
   }
}
```

In case you *have to* loop *forward* (e.g. if Instances should be deleted in the order they are created because they are depend on each other) you can modify for loop in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ObjectManager.Instance.Objects.Count;)  // <- No increment here
  if (ObjectManager.Instance.Objects[i] is Asteroid)
    ObjectManager.Instance.Objects.Remove(ObjectManager.Instance.Objects[i]);
  else 
    i += 1; // <- Increment should be here!
```

Yet another possibility is *Linq*:

```
ObjectManager.Instance.Objects.RemoveAll(item => item is Asteroid);
```

Answer (score 4):

Three options:

- If `ObjectManager.Instance.Objects` is a `List<T>`, use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a predicate, making your code *much* simpler:

  ```
  // This replaces your whole loop...
  ObjectManager.Instance.Objects.RemoveAll(x => x is Asteroid);
  ```
- Count from the *end* of the collection rather than from the start, so that you don't need to adjust the index afterwards:

  ```
  for (int i = ObjectManager.Instance.Objects.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  ```
- Just decrement `i` after calling `Remove`, so that you'll look at the right index on the next iteration.

Note that in the second and third options your code will be a lot simpler to read if you extract the expression `ObjectManager.Instance.Objects` into a local variable before you use it 4 times. Also consider using `RemoveAt(i)` rather than `Remove(instances[i])`, assuming `RemoveAt` is available for the type you're using.